# fgets not accepting last value?

Tags: c, scanf, newline, fgets, c-strings

I have a homework problem in which: -

> 1) User will input the number of names he wants to input.
>
> 2) He will then input those names.
>
> 3) We have to print those names.

This is the code I wrote for the above problem: -

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    int n; // number of names user wants to input.
    scanf("%d", &n);

    char *array[n]; //creating an array of pointers.

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        array[i] = malloc(21*sizeof(char)); // allocating memory to each pointer.
    }

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        fgets(array[i], 21, stdin); //getting the values.
    }

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", array[i]); // printing those values.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem with the above code is that it is not printing the last value inputted by the user.

Example: 
Sample Input: -

```
5
raj
chris
ben
abhay
gautam
```

Expected Output: -

```
raj
chris
ben
abhay
gautam
```

My Output: -

```
raj
chris
ben
abhay
```

Edit:

After changing this line: -

`scanf("%d", &n);`

to

`scanf("%d ", &n);`

it is working normally.

Comment: Where does 21 come from?

Comment: maximum size of name can only be 20. Size 21 because for adding `\0`.

Comment: when you print add some distinguishing mark, eg `printf("==> %s", array[i]);`, or `"**%s**"`, .... Or also print the loop variable: `printf("%d ==> %s", i, array[i]);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first `scanf("%d", &n);` left a newline in the input stream so your first string read by `fgets` is just a newline. You need to remove that newline before reading the names.

If you change

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    printf("%s", array[i]); // printing those values.
}
```

to

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    printf("String %d : |%s|", i, array[i]); // printing those values.
}
```

it is easy to see...

You'll get the output:

```
String 0 : |
|String 1 : |raj
|String 2 : |chris
|String 3 : |ben
|String 4 : |abhay
|
```

Notice how the first string is just a newline...

My usual advice is... Don't use `scanf`(for reading the number). It seems to be a very simple function but it's really very difficult to use and causes a lot of bugs. Instead use `fgets` followed by `sscanf`. Also you should check that `sscanf`/`scanf` actually returns 1.

Answer (score 1):

In the input buffer there is stored the new line character `'\n'` after the call

```
scanf("%d", &n);
```

Before using `fgets` you have to remove this character from the input buffer.

You can do it using this call

```
scanf( "%*[ \t\n]" );
```

Take also into account that fgets in turn can append a string with a new line character that in general should be removed from a string as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

Here is the demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { STRING_SIZE = 21 };

    size_t n;

    scanf( "%zu", &n );

    scanf( "%*[ \t\n]" );

    char **s = malloc( n * sizeof( char * ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) s[i] = malloc( STRING_SIZE );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        fgets( s[i], STRING_SIZE, stdin );
        s[i][strcspn( s[i], "\n" )] = '\0';
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) puts( s[i] );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) free( s[i] );
    free( s );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is as expected

```
raj
chris
ben
abhay
gautam
```

Comment: @snr It is de-facto a standard approach to remove the new line character from a string. It is not a bad coding. It is a normal coding.  It seems simply that you do not have enough knowledge of standard C string functions. So my answer is very useful for you.

Comment: I learn many new things while reading your code. Thanks for writing.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I could not understand the line `s[i][strcspn( s[i], "\n" )] = '\0';` in your code.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow if I didn't know its meaning, I'd speak up, no worry. Anyway, it still is "bad coding practicing" in my regard.

Comment: @SwarnimKhosla fgets appends the new line character to an entered string. To delete it from a string you find the position of the new line character using the function strcspn and set the corresponding character to '\0'.